# Drag elements from ScrollView to View

Tags: react-native

It is already a few days i am working an a case but can't manage. I have `View` and `ScrollView` in it, in `ScrollView` I can drag my elements but when trying to drag element from `ScrollView` to my view can't get it out from the `ScrollView`. My question is it possible to drag element from `ScrollView` to `View`, if yes, please help me how can I do it.